# weak convergent sequence on continuous function spaces

Tags: measure-theory

Let $K$ be a compact Hausdorff space. Suppose that $f$ is a non-negative, continuous function on $K$ and $\mu$ is a continuous linear functional on $C(K)$.

Question. Is there a sequence $(f_{n})_{n}$ in $C(K)$ such that $f_{n}>0$ for each $n$ and $\mu(f_{n})\rightarrow \mu(f)$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Am I misunderstanding the question or does $f_n=f+\frac 1n$ not work?